# Nexmo voice call without text to speech

Tags: c#, .net, vonage

We are developing an application and we want to use vonage/nexmo platform for calling to a phone number.

On nexmo platform i am getting API to call a number and give text to speech or IVR responses as input. However , i need to connect actual voice of an agent for this.

How can we send user voice without recording ? Can we use this platform for automated VoiP conversations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can connect the call to another number using the `connect` action in the NCCO.
See https://developer.nexmo.com/voice/voice-api/ncco-reference#connect for details

Comment: Any idea how to make a call from a browser based application which uses Nexmo API? There are things like In-App voice which seem like the right choice but I am not sure how to proceed.